# Docker Compose unable to use https

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appone.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apponeapi
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/AppOne.Api.pfx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AppOne.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - ${NETWORK}
    ports:
    - "59541:80"
    - "59542:443"
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      
networks:
  dev-network:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

When I try to connect to https://localhost:59542/values via Postman, it will fail saying

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection
> was established

This is how I start it:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --force-recreate --build -d
docker image prune -f
```

Am I missing something? If I remove https://+443 and the port 443 reference, I am able to connect using http only via port 59541

Comment: does (unencrypted) HTTP work? if you run `lsof` inside the container, does it show that something is listening on port 443? did you set up a certificate so that HTTPS can be served from that container?

Comment: Hi @root HTTP works if I remove the references to https in my docker compose and rebuild it. I am using the certificate set up using dev-certs. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know dev-certs (or Windows in general). But it looks like you're not alone: https://forums.docker.com/t/error-client-network-socket-disconnected-before-secure-tls-connection-was-established/125031 (unless that's you...)

Comment: Yeah that’s me. I managed to reach this stage and that is why I’m asking a new question.

Comment: Have you enabled HTTPS in Docker, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810165/run-docker-service-on-https

Comment: Hi @ralfhtp sorry I dont understand what does he mean by web server inside the docker application. Does he mean my .net core application? Or the Docker application? Both seem to be able to function on https because I have another similar project that can be accessed via https

Comment: Does the Dockerfile of your image include `EXPOSE 443` ? See answer of marvelTracker in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810165/run-docker-service-on-https

Comment: Yes it exposes 80 and 443.