# How do I get Weaviate running on HTTPS using Docker compose?

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, https, weaviate

I can't get Weaviate running on HTTPS in Docker.

I've been running Weaviate successfully on Docker over HTTP for a while.  I'm at the end of app development and want to secure the entire stack as best I can.  The first step is to get Weaviate running on HTTPS, and then apply an API key.  I tried following the (not exceptionally helpful) [instructions](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/configuration/authentication) without success.  I tried one step at a time and got the service running, but it wouldn't respond to HTTPS requests.  I tried searching here, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441673/docker-compose-unable-to-use-https), which is unanswered ('helpful' comments weren't that helpful).

Here's the HTTPS attempt:

```
> curl -v -k https://localhost:8080/v1/schema
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8080 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to localhost:8080
```

Here's the HTTP attempt:

```
> curl -v -k http://localhost:8080/v1/schema 
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /v1/schema HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Vary: Origin
< Date: Tue, 12 Sep 2023 19:57:01 GMT
< Content-Length: 15
< 
{"classes":[]}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

For HTTPS, my docker-compose.yml looked like this:

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - https
    - --tls-certificate
    - /etc/ssl/certs/dev-certificate.pem
    - --tls-key
    - /etc/ssl/certs/dev-private-key.pem
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.21.2
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: 'http://t2v-transformers:8080'
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-transformers'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-transformers'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  t2v-transformers:
    image: semitechnologies/transformers-inference:sentence-transformers-multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1
    environment:
      ENABLE_CUDA: '0'
volumes:
  weaviate_data:
...
```

I don't really want to deploy this app in a production environment with an insecure vector store.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the command options --tls-host and --tls-port instead like so :

```
  ---
version: '3.4'
services:
  weaviate:
    command:
    - --tls-host
    - 0.0.0.0
    - --tls-port
    - '8080'
    - --scheme
    - https
    - --tls-certificate
    - /etc/ssl/certs/dev-certificate.pem
    - --tls-key
    - /etc/ssl/certs/dev-private-key.pem
    image: semitechnologies/weaviate:1.21.2
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    volumes:
    - weaviate_data:/var/lib/weaviate
    - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    restart: on-failure:0
    environment:
      AUTHENTICATION_ANONYMOUS_ACCESS_ENABLED: 'true'
      TRANSFORMERS_INFERENCE_API: 'http://t2v-transformers:8080'
      QUERY_DEFAULTS_LIMIT: 25
      PERSISTENCE_DATA_PATH: '/var/lib/weaviate'
      DEFAULT_VECTORIZER_MODULE: 'text2vec-transformers'
      ENABLE_MODULES: 'text2vec-transformers'
      CLUSTER_HOSTNAME: 'node1'
  t2v-transformers:
    image: semitechnologies/transformers-inference:sentence-transformers-multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1
    environment:
      ENABLE_CUDA: '0'
volumes:
  weaviate_data:
...
```

Comment: You can also run Weaviate behind a reverse proxy, such as Traefik or NGINX. Here is a nice example on how to do it with traefik: https://gist.github.com/dudanogueira/0dd925cbf63397e256e84e991245aab3